# Response.write and ASP.NET controls

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Please see the code below:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Response.Write("<table><tr><td>some text</td></tr></table>")
        Response.Flush()
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)
        Response.Write("<table><tr><td>some text</td></tr></table>")
        Response.Flush()
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)
        Response.Write("<table><tr><td>some text</td></tr></table>")
        Response.Flush()
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)
        Response.Write("<table><tr><td>some text</td></tr></table>")
        Response.Flush()
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)
    End Sub
```

The code works as I would expect i.e. a HTML table is generated and written to the screen, then after three seconds another table is generated and added to the screen etc.

I have a webpage that dynamically adds x number of tables (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.table%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to a webpage.  However, Response.Flush does not seem to work.  I have created the simple code below to explain the problem:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim Table1 As New Table
        Dim r As New TableRow()
        Dim c As New TableCell()
        c.Text = "Test 1"
        r.Cells.Add(c)
        Table1.Rows.Add(r)
        Response.Flush()
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)

        Dim Table2 As New Table
        Dim r2 As New TableRow()
        Dim c2 As New TableCell()
        c.Text = "Test 2"
        r.Cells.Add(c)
        Table1.Rows.Add(r)
    End Sub
```

Is it possible to flush table1 to the client, then wait a few seconds then flush table2 or do you have to write a string to response.write?

Comment: You are not adding Table1 to the form. It needs to be part of the forms controls collection. Try adding a placeholder to the form, and then add the table to the placeholder.

Comment: @Craig Moore, it is added to a PlaceHolder control in the live app.

Comment: Your question is in regards to understand response.flush or resolve your problem?

Comment: @Dalorzo, both.  Is it possible to use response.flush with a page that contains web controls?

Comment: All the examples I can find are HelloWorld type examples i.e. flush a text item to the screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use `Response.Flush` in that way you need to output all the HTML code yourself using `Response.Write`.

You can't use web controls as they are not rendered until the page is complete. The web controls only exist as objects until the `Page_Render` stage where the entire page is rendered as HTML code and then sent to the browser.

Comment: Thanks for that +1.  Is there an alternative to response.flush, which allows web controls to be used? Perhaps an asynchronous approach to building a webpage.

Comment: @w0051977: Yes, you can send the page without the content and use AJAX to fetch more content. You can use plain Javascript and fetch HTML from a handler, or use `PageMethod` to call server code from Javascript, or use the AJAX support with update panels.

Comment: Can you post a link before I mark the answer? Perhaps this one: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178208%28v=vs.100%29.aspx.  I want to make sure I am on the right track.

Comment: @w0051977: Yes, that is one option. Here is a roadmap: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb398822.aspx

Comment: I assume that this works the first time a webpage loads as well as with postbacks?